# Trying to get an ImageView to scale as the screen gets bigger

Tags: android, image, android-layout, user-experience

I'm currently new to Android development, and I'm was trying to get an image to scale for different screen sizes. I made a drawable-hdpi,-mdpi, and drawable-xdpi. In these folders I placed the image but at different sizes for each screen density ( Ex. for xdpi, I made the image bigger). I placed the imageView in the constraint layout and set the height and weight to wrap_content. I was expecting the image to be the same size as the corresponding drawable, but for higher screen densities it was still super small. Any thoughts? I also read about 9 patch images, but I cant just add a larger image to the higher density drawable folders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change the scaleType of imageview.
 if you want to scale image with maintain aspect ratio you should use

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="fitcenter"/>
```

u can try another option like centerCrop and fitxy and see the result

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
        ....
```

Add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to ImageView to adjust the width and Height of view